# selecting from table a when not in table b

Tags: mysql

The following command selects all the items from 'stock' that appear in 'items' with the correct orderRef.

`SELECT a.* FROM stock a LEFT JOIN items b ON a.id = b.stockId WHERE b.orderRef='orderRef'`

This works, but I need all the items that aren't listed in table 'items' with the correct orderRef.

I thought I should change 'ON' to its opposite, but 'OFF' didn't work.

Comment: how can it have correct `orderRef` if it does not have a matching row in items ?

Comment: I add the orderRef with st->bindValue

Comment: yes but `orderRef` is in table b... and you want the rows from table a that does not have a entry in table b...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do a "not in" query is MySQL is the following:

```
select s.*
from stock s
where not exists (select 1 from items i where s.id = i.stockID and i.orderref = 'orderref' limit 1)
```

The way the MySQL optimizers works, the `not exists` performs best.  This can be further enhanced by having an index on items.stockID.

Note that when you use a left outer join, you may inadvertently be multiplying the nubmer of rows, if there are duplicates in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM stock a LEFT JOIN items b ON a.id = b.stockId WHERE 
                b.stockId is null and a.orderRef='orderRef'
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fix, but for this to work you have to have an orderRef field in your stock table, is that true?

Comment: no, items from the stock table populate the items table, which are seperated by stock id